# I got the certificate error when I want to migrate my database

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc, migration, database-migration

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC web app project, and my Entity Framework Core version is 7.0.9.

For example this is one of my class:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BusinessEntity
{
    public class CantactUs
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(50)")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(200)")]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(5000)")]
        public string definition { get; set; }

        public DateTime time { get; set; }

        public bool read { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I create my `Dbcontext` like this:

```
namespace DataAcessLayer
{
    public class DB : IdentityDbContext<User>
    {
        public DB() : base() { }

        public DB(DbContextOptions<DB> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder OptionsBuilder)
        {
            OptionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"data source=.;initial catalog = stor; integrated security = true;");
            base.OnConfiguring(OptionsBuilder);
        }

        //public DbSet<Book> Books { set; get; }

        public DbSet<CantactUs> cantactUs { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Comment> comments { get; set; }
}
```

I added my connection string in `appsettings.json`:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "CON1": "data source=.;initial catalog = stor; integrated security = true;"
```

But when I am using `add-migration` and `update-database`, I get this error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)

I do not know how to handle this, but after some search I find, I can change my connection string to this:

```
@"data source=.;initial catalog = stor; integrated security = true;TrustServerCertificate=True;"
```

The `TrustServerCertificate=True;` part solved my problem, but I have another problem now. I got this error after running `update-database` command

> The size (5000) given to the parameter 'definition' exceeds the maximum allowed (4000).

but I if right the maximum number of character of `nvarchar` is "2^31-1" - how can handle the certificate and size error?

Comment: You can define specific lengths for `nvarchar(n)` up to 4000 characters - or you can use `nvarchar(max)` which can handle 1 billion characters - but nothing in between. You cannot use `nvarchar(5000)` - as the error clearly states. [Details of NVARCHAR datatype clearly documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: thank you i going to try now. but can you help on first error too please?

Comment: The first error is solved by adding `TrustServerCertificate=true` - no?

Comment: True, but the links that gave this solution also said this solution is temporary and even though it solves the problem, it reduce the security and is not recommended. So I want the better solution if exist.

Comment: @sadegh _"So I want the better solution if exist."_  - follow the link in my answer, in mitigations the first one is "Install a valid certificate on the server.".

Comment: See the link in @GuruStron's answer - basically, for a proper resolution, you need to [install a valid server certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-sql-server-encryption?view=sql-server-ver16) on your SQL Servers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `nvarchar(max)`:

```cs
[Required, Column(TypeName = "nvarchar(max)")]
public string definition { get; set; }
```

From SQL Server [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#nvarchar---n--max--):

> `nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]`
> Variable-size string data. `n` defines the string size in byte-pairs, and **can be a value from 1 through 4,000**

As for the fixed problem - it is covered in EF Core 7 breaking changes - [`Encrypt` defaults to `true` for SQL Server connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#encrypt-true):

> #### Mitigations
>
> There are three ways to proceed:
>
> 1. Install a valid certificate on the server. Note that this is an involved process and requires obtaining a certificate and ensuring it is signed by an authority trusted by the client.
> 2. If the server has a certificate, but it is not trusted by the client, then `TrustServerCertificate=True` to allow bypassing the normal trust mechanims.
> 3. Explicitly add `Encrypt=False` to the connection string.

You have applied the second one. For non-development environments you should look into the first one.

Comment: thank you. So, now that I am developing offline on my laptop, my method is correct, but then I have to go to the first method?

Comment: @sadegh basically yes.